# VB 2010 How can i use to return a random sub folder and open that folder in windows explorer

Tags: vb.net, string, random, directory

How can I use VB 2010 to return a random sub directory and open that directory in windows explorer.

I have got a main directory C:\test\ and would like to open or display the path (as a string) of a random sub directory from within the test directory.

Ideally this would take me to the random directory when a button is pressed on a VB form.

I quiet new to Visual Basic so any help will be great.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following code

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    'Directory info for the starting folder.
    Dim DirectoryInfo1 As New IO.DirectoryInfo("C:\test\")
    'An array of all the subdirectories of the starting folder.
    Dim Directories1() As IO.DirectoryInfo = DirectoryInfo1.GetDirectories("*", IO.SearchOption.AllDirectories)

    'Random number generator.
    Dim Random1 As New Random
    'Gets a random index from the subdirectories array.
    Dim RandomIndex1 As Integer = Random1.Next(0, Directories1.Length - 1)

    'Shows the path of a random directory.
    MsgBox(Directories1(RandomIndex1).FullName)

    'Opens the random directory inside windows explorer.
    Process.Start("explorer.exe", Directories1(RandomIndex1).FullName)
End Sub
```